# If formula based on different values

Tags: excel, if-statement

Looking for a if formula to add up values based on the cell value.

If Cell Value x is then add:

```
x<=-7:+8 
-4<=x<=-6:+5 
-1<=x<=-3:+3
x=0:+2
1<=x<=3:+1
4<=x<=6:-1
7<=x<=9:-3
10<=x:-5
```

But i would need it to add up the points in the cells, n3, p3, r3, t3 all the way to BL3 (always skipping 1 column) values are in the array of N3:BL27 with results being in C31:C55

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F11

Assumptions: you have values in sheet1

Insert the below, and enable references to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Public Function GiveMeScores(RowID as Integer)
Dim icountcols as Integer
Dim isumscores as Integer
Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary
With dict
    .Add -6, 5
    .Add -5, 5
    .Add -4, 5
    .Add -3, 3
    .Add -2, 3
    .Add -1, 3
    .Add 0, 2
    .Add 1, 1
    .Add 2, 1
    .Add 3, 1
    .Add 4, -1
    .Add 5, -1
    .Add 6, -1
    .Add 7, -3
    .Add 8, -3
    .Add 9, -3
End With
For icountcols = 14 to 64 Step 2
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowID,icountcols).Value <= -7 Then
       isumscores = isumscores + 8
    ElseIF ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowID,icountcols).Value >= 10 Then
       isumscores = isumscores - 5
    Else
       isumscores = isumscores + dict.Item(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowID,icountcols).Value)
    End If
Next icountcols

GiveMeScores = isumscores
End Function
```

Comment: it is sheet3 and renamed handicap

Answer (score 0):

Formula solution:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(N3:BL3),2)=0,LOOKUP(N3:BL3,{-100,-6,-3,0,1,4,4,10},{8,5,3,2,1,-1,-3,-5}),0))
```

It is an array formula, so be sure to confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: when using this formula, it starts out with 52points, and the point values are off. ie: -1 only gives 1pt instead of 3points